# Is 'most often' synonymous with 'usually'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I referred to a number of dictionaries to no avail. What does ***most often*** exactly mean?

> While efforts to prevent student violence are ***most often***
> promoted following high-profile school shootings, they can also be a
> critical tool for promoting safety in the larger community, school
> safety experts say.

[Preventing Student Violence: 3 Key Takeaways](https://www.edweek.org/leadership/preventing-student-violence-3-key-takeaways/2022/05)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it means that efforts to prevent student violence are *usually* or *most commonly* promoted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is synonymous with *usually.* It means what it says; if something happens often, it happens on many occasions, and if it happens *most* often it happens on the greatest number of occasions.